# Odds of winning contest

Tags: probability

I enter a contest every week with $850$ others that I have a random chance of being selected as the winner.  There is only one winner.  If I play for $850$ weeks, should I have a $100\%$ chance of being a winner?

Comment: If you flip a coin twice, is there a 100% chance that it comes up heads at least once?

Comment: What are your chances of losing? What are your chances of losing every time after $850$ weeks?

Comment: Only if the rules state that there can be no new entrants, and once you have won once, you are ineligible to win a second time.

Comment: You are *expected* to win one time, but that is the average of the of the times you win $0$ times in 850 days, the times you win one time in 850 days, the times you win 2 times in 850 days, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of beeing selected at least once is One minus the probability of beeing never selected (converse probability)

$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$,

where $X$ is the random variable of beeing selected in 850 weeks. It is binomial distributed:

$X\sim Bin(850,p)$

$P(X=0)=\binom{850}{0}\cdot p^0\cdot (1-p)^{850}=(1-p)^{850}$

p is the probability of beeing selected in one week.

$1-P(X=0)$ is $1$ if $P(X=0)=0$.

We can assume that $p<1$. It is possible that $(1-p)^{850}$ becomes $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that you win at least once is:

$$1-\left(1-\frac{1}{850}\right)^{850}$$

Comment: Assuming that you meant $850$ people including yourself (if you meant $851$ people altogether, then replace the inner "$850$" with "$851$")...

Comment: +1, and good catch on the potential off-by-one error. :-)

Answer (score -2):

The winning chances are independent of each other. So, for every match you have chance of 1 for 850 members. Even if you play for infinite times, there is no guarantee for 100% winning. So for 850 matches you have probability of winning as

> 1/(850)^ 850

The above case is probability for winning in all the 850 matches.

The probability for winning atleast once is binomial. It is

> 1 - ( losing all the times ).

Losing all the times is  (no. of players - 1) / no. of players raised to power of no. of matches played

Comment: So, the more times you play, the less likely you are to ever win?

Comment: No, the probability is less likely. It is independent event. It doesn't depend on previous plays. So, it is multiplied.

Comment: This gives probability of winning every time- the question asked for probability of winning at least once.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I gave for winning all the times.

Comment: @Sameer: That is *not* what the question asks for.  The question asks for the probability that the OP wins *at least* once.

Comment: Many thanks for the responses.  I have to admit that you all are operating at a level way above my pay grade, so I'm not sure If I understand the answer.  It seems like every contest is unique with a one in 850 chance, and playing 850 times does not improve my odds.  This, by the way, is a real life problem.  Every Friday, the Wall St Journal has a crossword puzzle contest.  On average there are 850 correct answers, and one person is randomly chosen from that cohort to win a mug.  It seems like I could play forever and never win.